# Calculate number of events for next weeks

Tags: date, calendar, applescript

I need to calculate number of events for several next weeks. But my approach is too slow (*working time is more than 1.5 hour*). How I can speed up this script? Currently I'm getting all events of the calendar every time for each `weekNumber`... This is very slow but I can't figure out **how I can get all events only once and have weekNumber for each event**.

```
tell application "Calendar"

    set theCalendars to name of calendars

    repeat with theCalendar in theCalendars

        set listCurrentCalendar to {}
        set end of listCurrentCalendar to theCalendar

        repeat with weekNumber from 1 to 13
            set currentWeekMonday to my DateOfThisInstanceOfThisWeekdayBeforeOrAfterThisDate(current date, Monday, weekNumber)
            set nextWeekMonday to my DateOfThisInstanceOfThisWeekdayBeforeOrAfterThisDate(current date, Monday, weekNumber + 1)

            set numberOfEvents to 0
            set TheEvents to events of calendar theCalendar
            repeat with anEvent in TheEvents

                set eventStartDate to start date of anEvent
                if eventStartDate ≥ currentWeekMonday and eventStartDate ≤ nextWeekMonday then
                    set numberOfEvents to numberOfEvents + 1
                end if
            end repeat

            set end of listCurrentCalendar to numberOfEvents
        end repeat

        set end of listData to listCurrentCalendar
    end repeat

end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for two weeks:

```
set myEvents to {}

tell application "iCal"
    set myCalendars to calendars
    repeat with aCalendar in myCalendars
        set calEvents to (every event of aCalendar whose start date > (current date) and end date < ((current date) + (2 * weeks)))
        if calEvents ≠ {} then set myEvents to myEvents & calEvents
    end repeat
end tell
```